# cURL newest version on Debia Squeeze

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, curl, repository

Why Debian Squeeze repositories points to cURL version 7.21.0 which is from June 2010 and not the version 7.26.0 which is from May of this year([cURL Changelog](http://curl.haxx.se/changes.html))??

I want to update to the version 7.26 to avoid NTLM bugs, can I do this or it will crash the system in any way? If yes, how do I do it??

Comment: Debian strives for stability and upgrading packages for everyone 6 days after something came out is a good way to make sure you never achieve that goal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian 6.0 (squeeze) was released in 2011, so it can not come with current version of CURL. You will receive mostly security updates while this release is supported.

You can try to find a more recent version (.deb file). Otherwise, you need to build your own!

Comment: Thank you, this explain more http://qa.debian.org/developer.php?login=rkrishnan%40debian.org